# Last item in the c# list

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I am need to highlight the keywords or tags in an article & pass variable to jQuery Array 
i am using property to pass value from C# to java-script which works i also need to format my keywords which in database are stored like `one, two, three, four, five,six,seven`

in order to make it work i have to wrap each keyword in single `'`  or double quotes`"`.

**JQuery**

```
    function HighlightKeywords(keywords) {
        var el = $("body");
        $(keywords).each(function () {
            var pattern = new RegExp("(" + this + ")", ["gi"]);
            var rs = "<a href='search.aspx?search=$1'<span style='background-color:#FFFF00;font-weight: bold;background-color:#FFFF00;'>$1</span></a>";
            el.html(el.html().replace(pattern, rs));
        });
    }

HighlightKeywords(["<%= MyProperty %>]");
```

C# Code

```
string _sFinalList = null;

protected string MyProperty { get { return _sFinalList; } }
string sKewords = "one, two, three, four, five,six,seven";

List<string> lstKewords = sKewords.Split(',').ToList();
foreach (string list in lstKewords) // Loop through List with foreach
{
   _sFinalList += "'" + list + "',";
```

}

Problem with this code is that it ads `,` after the last words i want to know what is the best way to avoid adding `,` after the last words

**Current OUTPUT**: "'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five','six','seven',"

**Desired OUTPUT**: "'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five','six','seven'"

Help in this regard is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, use [`String.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) :

```
List<string> lstKeywords = sKeywords.Split(',').ToList();

var quotedKeywords = lstKeywords.Select(s => "'" + s + "'");

string _sFinalList = string.Join(",", quotedKeywords);
```

Comment: `Join()` solves your last-one-is-different issue. `Select()` is a Linq operator to create an intermediate result.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `String.Join()`

```
string sKewords = "one, two, three, four, five,six,seven";
List<string> lstKewords = sKewords.Split(',').ToList();
var _partial = lstKewords.Select(x => "'" + x + "'");
Var _result = String.Join(",", _partial);
```

- [String.Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx)

Comment: It gives me the same output `"one, two, three, four, five,six,seven"`

Comment: you fixed it now this was missing `var _partial = lstKewords.Select(x => "'" + x + "'");`

Comment: sorry for the typo. `Select()` is a linq extension method. It wraps each element with quotes using lambda. the result of the linq is an enumerable which is then pass on `String.Join()` which concatenates each element.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/tk0xe5h0.aspx)

```
var result = string.Format("'{0}'", string.Join("','", yourList));
```

Comment: Correct, but the way you get the outer quotes is s a little 'tricky'.

Answer (score 0):

you may simply remove lastIndexOf(",") with substring function of string class after you complete the for loop.

OR

you may add and if statement in your for loop that would add "," if loop is not in its last iteration.